# Array with array inside

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, nsmutablearray

I need to create an array with personal name inside,and on this name,another array with personal information.Basically an array with another array inside divided by name.

```
Es:Array[luca [born:x age:y lives:z] marco[born:x age:y lives:z]......}
```

How can i do that?

Comment: It would probably be best to create a simple array of custom Person objects, that would have properties of age, date of birth, lives, etc.

Comment: AN `NSDictionary` of `NSDictionary`s is common, using some unique key on the outer dictionary (for searching). Use `NSMutableDictionary` if you'll be modifying it. Also, there's `Core Data`.

Comment: Why not have the name as another property within your dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, use modern Objective-C literals.

```
NSDictionary *luca = @{@"name" : @"luca",
                       @"born" : @(1997),
                       @"lives" : @(5)};

NSDictionary *marc = @{@"name" : @"marc",
                       @"born" : @(1998),
                       @"lives" : @(2)};


NSArray *people = @[luca, marc];
```

Comment: Eh, but the name becomes just a variable name in this case and thus inaccessible as a string...

Comment: Yeah, I asked the OP why he doesn't want to do that in the comment below my answer... But yeah, it would make sense to add that to your answer.

Comment: Credit where credit is due. The OP's question was asking how to do it with basic collections, so I stuck with that. But if the OP would also ask if it is the right approach, I concur with @IanMacdonald that proper model objects are way better.

Answer (score 1):

Your brief description indicates that you might want a dictionary of dictionaries. However, what you want here is an array of dictionaries or an array of objects.

```
var people = [ ["name": "Luca", "born": x, "age": y, "lives": z],
                ... ]
```

or

```
struct Person {
  var name:String
  var born:Int16
  var age:Int16
  var lives:Int16
}

var array = [Person(name: "Luca", born: x, age: y, lives: z),
             ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

To add onto these answers you can also easily create a mutable `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSMutableArray` using literal syntax as follows:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [@{@"asdf":@"asdf"} mutableCopy];

NSMutableArray *arr = [@[@"asdf"] mutableCopy];
```